# Chainlink Job Request With Bridge: error making http request: Post "http://localhost:8080": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

Tags: json-rpc, oracles, chainlink, external-api, connections

I am trying to run my chainlink external adapter with a job in my node. However, every time I get an error at "fetch bridge" task: `error making http request: Post "http://localhost:8080": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused`

[image]

My external adapter is running on localhost:8080 and I can successfully perform curl commands like `curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "http://localhost:8080/" --data '{"id": 1, "data": { "playerId": 90026231 }}'`

Here is my Bridge configuration:

[image]

And here my JobSpecs:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Soccer-Data-EA"
contractAddress = "0xF59646024204a733E1E4f66B303c9eF4f68324cC"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=bridge name="sports-data" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": { \\"playerId\\": $(decode_cbor.playerId)}}"]
    parse        [type=jsonparse path="data,0,Games" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0xF59646024204a733E1E4f66B303c9eF4f68324cC" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "d5a37166-2c83-461b-9912-97beebe4d213"
```

Here my index.js i.e. my external adapter:

```
const { Requester, Validator } = require('@chainlink/external-adapter')
require('dotenv').config()

// Define custom error scenarios for the API.
// Return true for the adapter to retry.
const customError = (data) => {
  if (data.Response === 'Error') return true
  return false
}

// Define custom parameters to be used by the adapter.
// Extra parameters can be stated in the extra object,
// with a Boolean value indicating whether or not they
// should be required.
const customParams = {
  playerId: ['playerId'],
  endpoint: false
}

const createRequest = (input, callback) => {
  // The Validator helps you validate the Chainlink request data
  const validator = new Validator(callback, input, customParams)
  const jobRunID = validator.validated.id

  const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY
  const pId = validator.validated.data.playerId


  const url = `https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/soccer/stats/json/PlayerSeasonStatsByPlayer/1/${pId}?key=${apiKey}`


  const params = {
    pId
  }

  // This is where you would add method and headers
  // you can add method like GET or POST and add it to the config
  // The default is GET requests
  // method = 'get' 
  // headers = 'headers.....'
  const config = {
    url,
    params
  }

  // The Requester allows API calls be retry in case of timeout
  // or connection failure
  Requester.request(config, customError)
    .then(response => {
      // It's common practice to store the desired value at the top-level
      // result key. This allows different adapters to be compatible with
      // one another.
      //response.data.result = Requester.validateResultNumber(response.data, [tsyms])

      
      callback(response.status, Requester.success(jobRunID, response))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      callback(500, Requester.errored(jobRunID, error))
    })
}

// This is a wrapper to allow the function to work with
// GCP Functions
exports.gcpservice = (req, res) => {
  createRequest(req.body, (statusCode, data) => {
    res.status(statusCode).send(data)
  })
}

// This is a wrapper to allow the function to work with
// AWS Lambda
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  createRequest(event, (statusCode, data) => {
    callback(null, data)
  })
}

// This is a wrapper to allow the function to work with
// newer AWS Lambda implementations
exports.handlerv2 = (event, context, callback) => {
  createRequest(JSON.parse(event.body), (statusCode, data) => {
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: statusCode,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      isBase64Encoded: false
    })
  })
}

// This allows the function to be exported for testing
// or for running in express
module.exports.createRequest = createRequest
```

The index.js from above gets rendered in app.js see code below (same directory as index.js):

```
const createRequest = require('./index').createRequest

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.EA_PORT || 8080

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('POST Data: ', req.body)
  createRequest(req.body, (status, result) => {
    console.log('Result: ', result)
    res.status(status).json(result)
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Does somebody see what's wrong here with my code or configuration?

REMARK:

I saw that in app.js the directory in `const createRequest = require('./index').createRequest` the "./index" is wierd, because index.js and app.js are in the same directory. However, I can still perform `curl` like mentioned before and also when I put index.js in a index folder it doesn't change nothing.

Comment: What does your curl return?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your configuration except for the `Bridge URL` you set. Since `chainlink-node` and `external-adapter` are running in different docker containers, the API call made from `chainlink-node` to `localhost`, is executed internally to the Docker container, so the connection is refused.

You can simulate the same behaviour doing the steps below:

1. run `docker container ls` to copy the `container id` of the `chainlink-node`
2. run `docker exec -it {container_id} sh`
3. run `curl http://localhost:8000`

You will see the error `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused`.

To fix your problem, without creating a superstructure, you can get the internal IP address of your `external-adapter` and use it as `Bridge URL`. Follow these steps to get the internal IP address correctly:

1. run `docker container ls` to copy the `container id` of the `external-adapter`
2. run `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' {container_id}`

You will get the IP address to be used as `Bridge URL`.